# Change tab name in custom layout possible?

Tags: ee3, publish-layout

I'm trying to change the tab name in a custom entry publish layout, but it doesn't seem possible. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't change tab labels at present - you'll need to create a new tab instead and move your fields to it from the old tab.